# Pick dropped items in fountain

Tags: dota-2

How to pick all dropped items instantly. [Here](https://youtu.be/k-d8zbDO350?t=1736) Funkefal does it in the fountain.

So, he basically shift-queues and drop all the items while re-arming but then picks them up instantly.

I understand that there is a hotkey to get stash items but it doesn't work for dropped items. How does he do it?
One more [link](https://youtu.be/k-d8zbDO350?t=1813)

Answer (score 3):

That's not what is happening in the video. In that clip, the Tinker drops the Aether Lens and the Dagon, then picks them back up by just clicking on them.

Comment: I'll add another clip in 2 min. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the new link

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there's anything weird happening there.

Comment: He picked like 3 items instantly. IS he doing it manually or some shift-queueing

Comment: I've answered your question.